# Reading a file with paragraphs in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, xcode, file

So I'm trying to read a text file with multiple lines of words and I would like to store in an array. I have tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE * fptr;
    char str1;

    fptr = fopen ("test1.txt", "r");
    printf("\n The content of the file is  :\n");
    str1 = fgetc(fptr);
    while (str1 != EOF)
    {
        printf ("%c", str1);
        str1 = fgetc(fptr);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    fclose (fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

But I receive this in the console:

```
The content of the file is  :
(lldb)
```

(I'm using xCode on Mac)

Are there problems with the code or is it with xCode? Thank you!

EDIT:
The content of the text file is:

```
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx
yz
```

I forgot to include: on the line

```
str1 = fgetc(fptr);
```

xCode has it highlighted orange(?) saying

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x68)
```

I have no idea what it means

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` by intention.

Comment: Please add the content (or an example) of your input file, to improve your [mcve].

Comment: You need to check if `fopen` returns `NULL` which means that the file could not be opened for some reason.

Comment: `char str1;`-> `int str1;`

Comment: OK, so the result is `The content of the file is  :
(lldb)`.  What did you expect?  What is the content of `test1.txt`?  Did file open succeed?  Are there problems with the code or is it with xCode? --> the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Turns out this was a derp. I completely forgot that I had changed the file name to test and didn't notice the difference of "1" until I added a code to see if the program actually opened the file or not. Thank you all for helping!